# Choosing a set of values in an array

Tags: julia

The following code

```
a=1:1:10
collect(a)
a[a.>4]
```

returns the expected

```
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

Whereas,

```
a[(a.>4) & (a.<8)]
```

returns

```
MethodError: no method matching &(::Int64, ::StepRange{Int64,Int64})
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `a.>4` and `a.<8` return `BitArray`s, you need to broadcast `&` with a dot (`.`) as well.

```
julia> a[(a.>4) .& (a.<8)]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5
 6
 7
```

Comment: I wanted to get elements 5, 6, 7. Correction : a[(a.>4) .& (a.<8)]

Comment: @SchlatorBorgenson Yep, suspected something was weird, especially the error message you get. `collect(a)` does not modify `a`. So `a` remains a range object. Also there was operator precedence issue. so `a.>4 .& a` is evaluated first and then `.< 8`. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternative ways of doing it:

```
julia> a = 1:10

julia> a[4 .< a .< 8]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5
 6
 7

julia> filter(x->4<x<8, a)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5
 6
 7
```

Oh, and don't use `collect`.